# 接続助詞は名詞修飾節の中に使えますか？・接続助詞で作る文は他の接続助詞で作る文を修飾できますか？

Tags: grammar, syntax

偶然この質問を思い出しました。

## Question 1

英語で

> Hey, look! The car over there is the car which I would buy if I were rich.

という文があると思います。

その「if I were rich」は従属接続詞（if）で「I would buy」を修飾しているのです。それだけではなく、実は「I would buy」と「if I were rich」は「which I would buy if I were rich」の中の一部です。とりあえず、両方とも名詞修飾節の一部です。

そういうわけで、日本語もそういう使い方があるかを考えています。

例えば、

> 明日早く起きたら食べられる朝ごはんはアイスクリームです。

「たら」を使って「明日早く起きたら」で「食べられる」を修飾します。そして、「明日早く起きたら食べられる」は朝ごはんを修飾します。

例えば、

> 子供がうるさいのでたまらない父はイヤホンをつけた。

「ので」を使って「子供がうるさいので」で「たまらない」を修飾します。そして、「子供がうるさいのでたまらない」は父を修飾します。

## Question 2

英語で時々従属接続詞で作る文が他の従属接続詞で作る文を修飾する場合もあります。

例えば、

> By the time she saw the boy, he had already escaped the scene because nobody was there to attack him when he decided to pass through the narrow way.
>
> from No Grammar Tears 2
>
> 途中で何か良い物を拾ったら半分はヘルメスの神に捧げるから、無事に旅をさせてくれといったものです。
>
> from イソップ童話

これは「途中で何か良い物を拾ったら」で「半分はヘルメスの神に捧げるから」を修飾しているのですか？

そして「途中で何か良い物を拾ったら半分はヘルメスの神に捧げるから」は「無事に旅をさせてくれといったものです」を修飾しているのですか？

---

以上の通りに接続助詞で名詞修飾節の文を修飾できますか？

接続助詞で作る文は他の接続助詞で作る文を修飾できますか？

一体この文法の使い方があるのかどうかを教えてください。

Are they just like adverbial clauses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Question 1**

可能です。ただし挙げてくださった例文は、実際はあまり使われないでしょう。なぜなら

> [明日早く起きたら] [食べられる朝ごはんはアイスクリームです。]
>   [子供がうるさいので] [たまらない父はイヤホンをつけた。]

という構造に解釈する方が自然なので、そう誤解される可能性が高いからです。
以下のように、被修飾語が最後に来る文であれば一般的です。

> こちらがポイントを貯めるともらえる景品です。

「ポイントを貯めるともらえる」が「景品」を修飾しています。

**Question 2**

これも可能です。ただし説明にある

> そして「途中で何か良い物を拾ったら半分はヘルメスの神に捧げるから」は「無事に旅をさせてくれといったものです」を修飾しているのですか？

は正しくありません。「途中で何か良い物を拾ったら半分はヘルメスの神に捧げるから」は「無事に旅をさせてくれ」を修飾し、「途中で～させてくれ」全体が引用文 (narration) として、「といったものです」に接続します。

Answer (score 0):

Questionへの答えですが、全部YESです。

「子供がうるさいのでたまらない父はイヤホンをつけた」は、実際は「…うるさくて たまらない父は…」のほうが自然です。しかし、いずれにせよ「ので」節で修飾された節が名詞を修飾することは問題ありません。

Off Topicですが、「実は彼ら(I would buy と if I were rich)は”which I would buy if I were rich”の中に一部です」は、正しくは「実はそれら(…)は”…"の中の一部…」です。